# How to Add date range to sasprompts in vba

Tags: vba, excel, sas

Im struggling with a kind of problem. I want to download data from sas portal via vba code in Excel. Sas portal has prompts where u need enter data range (at this specific stored process).

I dont know how to write variable date range in vba which could be pass through the prompt.

Here's the code:

```
Sub SAS_Downloader()

Dim sas As SASExcelAddIn

Set sas = Application.COMAddIns.Item("SAS.ExcelAddIn").Object

Dim daterange As SASRanges
Dim prompts As SASPrompts
Set prompts = New SASPrompts

prompts.Add "date_range", "01Jun2011,01Jun2011,01Jun2011,02Jun2011,02Jun2011,02Jun2011"


Dim a1 As Range
Set a1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
sas.InsertStoredProcess "Poland/Reports/Documents/Stored Process Raport", a1, prompts
```

End Sub

PS. The code work very well when the prompts are not data range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out!

On SAS support site, there is a PDF, which contains macros whois can be parse into SASPrompts, so **date_range** can be parse as **date_range_min** and **date_range_max**

```
  Dim prompts As SASPrompts
  Set prompts = New SASPrompts

  prompts.Add "date_range_min", "01Jun2011"
  prompts.Add "date_range_max", "10Jun2011"
```

Here other type macros:

http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/309-2011.pdf